# produce hfiles for multiple tables to bulk load in a single map reduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I am using `mapreduce` and `HfileOutputFormat` to produce `hfiles` and bulk load them directly into the `hbase` table.

Now, while reading the input files, I want to produce `hfiles` for two tables and bulk load the outputs in a single `mapreduce`.

I searched the web and see some links about `MultiHfileOutputFormat` and couldn't find a real solution to that.

Do you think that it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

My way is :

1. use HFileOutputFormat as well, when the job is completed , doBulkLoad, write into table1.
2. set a List puts in mapper, and a MAX_PUTS value in global.

when `puts.size()>MAX_PUTS`, do:

```
String tableName = conf.get("hbase.table.name.dic", table2); 
HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
table.setAutoFlushTo(false);
table.setWriteBufferSize(1024*1024*64);             
table.put(puts);
table.close();
puts.clear();
```

notice:you mast have a cleanup function to write the left puts .

Comment: Your second solution doesn't include bulk loading. what I need is that, one mapreduce must create necessary HFiles for bulk loading to more than one table.